# How can I find the gcp service name related with the cost on google account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

Using bq data, we are able to list like

```
  {
    "svc_desc": "Cloud function",
    "service_id": "6F81-5220-406A",
    "labels": "null",
    "final_cost": "10.0"
  },
  {
    "svc_desc": "Cloud function",
    "service_id": "5490-F789-0DF2",
    "labels": "null",
    "final_cost": "20.0"
  }
```

If I request the google billing endpoint passing the service_id like https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5220-456A/skus?key={api_key}

This will show a list of skus but this don't have the real name of the resource just shows "its a cloud function". Someone know how we can get the names of the cloud functions related with those costs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on the Billing Catalog API.

[Google Cloud Billing Catalog API](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-billing-catalog-api/)

This displayName is `.skus[].category.serviceDisplayName`.

**Example:**

```
curl https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus?key=API_KEY
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "skus": [
    {
      "name": "services/6F81-5844-456A/skus/0009-EA63-4404",
      "skuId": "0009-EA63-4404",
      "description": "Licensing Fee for Bitnami RabbitMQ (CPU cost)",
      "category": {
        "serviceDisplayName": "Compute Engine",
        "resourceFamily": "License",
        "resourceGroup": "BitnamiRabbitMQ",
        "usageType": "OnDemand"
      },
      "serviceRegions": [
        "global"
      ],
      "pricingInfo": [
        {
          "summary": "",
          "pricingExpression": {
            "usageUnit": "h",
            "usageUnitDescription": "hour",
            "baseUnit": "s",
            "baseUnitDescription": "second",
            "baseUnitConversionFactor": 3600,
            "displayQuantity": 1,
            "tieredRates": [
              {
                "startUsageAmount": 0,
                "unitPrice": {
                  "currencyCode": "USD",
                  "units": "0",
                  "nanos": 0
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "currencyConversionRate": 1,
          "effectiveTime": "2018-10-28T03:11:58.735Z"
        }
      ],
      "serviceProviderName": "Google"
    },
```

Comment: Hello John thanks for your answer, yeah i have this information too like your answer this is a compute engine but do you know which one ? I mean i know it's a "Cloud Function" on display name but i want to know which cloud function is that. The real name of the resource like "test-function" for example

Comment: Did you read my article? Edit your question to include information on what you have and exactly what you are looking for. The billing catalog API does not have information on your resources names, only resources. For example, you mention `real resources name`. What does that mean exactly? Improve your question to get a good answer.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the suggestions, i've edited my question. I want to know the name of the cloud function related with the cost. I have a big list of cloud functions on my account and some of them are without labels which i can't identify which one is missing labels. So i want to identify the name of the functions with this cost or how i can identify which gcf is without label on my account

Comment: You need to use the Billing API and not the Billing Catalog API